# Cannot get Tomcat 8 to use log4j (HELP!)

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I've been beating my head on a hard stone wall for 2 days now and am looking for some help...

I'm trying to get Tomcat 8 to use log4j for its own logging (my servlets already use log4j via their own log4j.properties) so that I can use the RollingFileAppender to manage the Tomcat log files (automatic log file rotation). I have yet to get Tomcat to actually log via log4j.  Each time it appears to use the default logger and write to

```
$catalina.base/logs/commons-daemon.{date}.log
$catalina.base/logs/{servlet}-stdout.{date}.log
$catalina.base/logs/{servlet}-stderr.{date}.log
```

Tomcat 8.0.29 is running as a Windows Service (tested on Windows 10 and Server 2012 R2).  I've tried letting it run normally via "net start XXX" as well as running from the terminal/cmd via "Tomcat8.exe //TS//XXX"  Neither result in tomcat using log4j.

I have followed the directions for using log4j from https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html

Here is edited copy of commons-daemon-{date}.log which shows how Tomcat is being run:

```
[debug] ( prunsrv.c:1679) [ 3976] Commons Daemon procrun log initialized
[info]  ( prunsrv.c:1683) [ 3976] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[info]  ( prunsrv.c:1596) [ 3976] Running 'CertAccord' Service...
[debug] ( prunsrv.c:1374) [ 3720] Inside ServiceMain...
[debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 3720] reportServiceStatusE: 2, 0, 3000, 0
[info]  ( prunsrv.c:1127) [ 3720] Starting service...
[debug] ( javajni.c:233 ) [ 3720] loading jvm 'C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\java\bin\server\jvm.dll'
[debug] ( javajni.c:278 ) [ 3720] Setting DLL search path to 'C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\java\bin\server'
[debug] ( javajni.c:278 ) [ 3720] Setting DLL search path to 'C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\java\bin'
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[0] -Dmc.debug=1
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[1] -Dcmb.productdir=C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[2] -Dcmb.datadir=C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[3] -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\tomcat
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[4] -Dcatalina.base=C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[5] -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\tomcat\endorsed
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[6] -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\temp
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[7] -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-tomcat.properties
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[8] -Dlog4j.debug=true
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[9] -Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\resource;C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\resource
[debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 3964] Jvm Option[10] exit
[debug] ( javajni.c:888 ) [ 3964] argv[0] = start
[debug] ( javajni.c:941 ) [ 3964] Java Worker thread started org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap:main
[debug] ( prunsrv.c:1186) [ 3720] Java started org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap
[info]  ( prunsrv.c:1284) [ 3720] Service started in 1211 ms.
[debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 3720] reportServiceStatusE: 4, 0, 0, 0
```

I also tried (without effect) to run tomcat using

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

The "log4j-tomcat.properties" file is located in C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\resource  I originally left the file name "log4j.properties" and did not define log4j.configure=log4j-tomcat.properties.  That also did not result in tomcat using log4j.

I replaced tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar with the download from apache extras.  I also added log4j-1.2.17.jar, apache-log4j-extra-1.2.17.jar, and tomcat-juli-adapters.jar to tomcat/lib:

```
bin:
total 2620
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   28417 Nov 20 01:19 bootstrap.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   13825 Nov 20 01:19 catalina.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   21389 Nov 20 01:19 catalina.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    1686 Nov 20 01:19 catalina-tasks.xml
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   24283 Nov 20 01:19 commons-daemon.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  204944 Nov 20 01:19 commons-daemon-native.tar.gz
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    2040 Nov 20 01:19 configtest.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    1922 Nov 20 01:19 configtest.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    7888 Nov 20 01:19 daemon.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    2091 Nov 20 01:19 digest.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    1965 Nov 20 01:19 digest.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    6308 Nov 20 01:19 service.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    3430 Nov 20 01:19 setclasspath.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    3547 Nov 20 01:19 setclasspath.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    2020 Nov 20 01:19 shutdown.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    1902 Nov 20 01:19 shutdown.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    2022 Nov 20 01:19 startup.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    1904 Nov 20 01:19 startup.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 1603072 Nov 20 01:19 tcnative-1.dll
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  109696 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat8.exe
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  110208 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat8w.exe
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   40845 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-juli.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   40845 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-juli.jar.OLD
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  388787 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-native.tar.gz
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    4057 Nov 20 01:19 tool-wrapper.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    5061 Nov 20 01:19 tool-wrapper.sh
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    2026 Nov 20 01:19 version.bat
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    1908 Nov 20 01:19 version.sh

lib:
total 8192
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   17353 Nov 20 01:19 annotations-api.jar
-rwx------+ 1 administrator  Domain Users  448797 Mar 21 11:15 apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 1550387 Nov 20 01:19 catalina.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   53033 Nov 20 01:19 catalina-ant.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  120065 Nov 20 01:19 catalina-ha.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   74655 Nov 20 01:19 catalina-storeconfig.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  270501 Nov 20 01:19 catalina-tribes.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 2310271 Nov 20 01:19 ecj-4.4.2.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   81428 Nov 20 01:19 el-api.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  586116 Nov 20 01:19 jasper.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  161367 Nov 20 01:19 jasper-el.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   61417 Nov 20 01:19 jsp-api.jar
-rwx------+ 1 administrator  Domain Users  489883 Mar 21 10:56 log4j-1.2.17.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  244281 Nov 20 01:19 servlet-api.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    8973 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-api.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  709490 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-coyote.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  244813 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-dbcp.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   67841 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-i18n-es.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   41471 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   43588 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  135939 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-jdbc.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   31475 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-jni.jar
-rwx------+ 1 administrator  Domain Users   21683 Mar 21 10:56 tomcat-juli-adapters.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  105125 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-util.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  201024 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-util-scan.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  211999 Nov 20 01:19 tomcat-websocket.jar
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   36603 Nov 20 01:19 websocket-api.jar
```

Here is log4j-tomcat.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CATALINA

# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
log4j.appender.CATALINA.MaxFileSize = 10M
log4j.appender.CATALINA.MaxBackupIndex = 5
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.MaxFileSize = 10M
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.MaxBackupIndex = 5
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/manager
log4j.appender.MANAGER.MaxFileSize = 10M
log4j.appender.MANAGER.MaxBackupIndex = 5
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %m%n

log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.MaxFileSize = 10M
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.MaxBackupIndex = 5
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %m%n

# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] = INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] = INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

This is what {servlet}-stderr.{date}.log looks like:

```
2016-03-22 12:47:39 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CaBridge' did not find a mat
ching property.
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebApp' did not find a match
ing property.
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.29
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 20 2015 09:18:00 UTC
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.29.0
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows Server 2012 R2
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\java
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_71-b15
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\tomcat
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dmc.debug=1
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcmb.productdir=C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcmb.datadir=C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\tomcat
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\CertAccordServer\tomcat\endorsed
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\temp
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-tomcat.properties
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dlog4j.debug=true
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: exit
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.1.
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015)
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3551 ms
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.29
Mar 22, 2016 12:47:58 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2016 12:48:20 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2016 12:48:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\CaBridge.war
Mar 22, 2016 12:48:40 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2016 12:48:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\CaBridge.war has finished in 17,015 ms
Mar 22, 2016 12:48:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
Mar 22, 2016 12:48:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\WebApp.war
Mar 22, 2016 12:48:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:02 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\WebApp.war has finished in 23,000 ms
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\host-manager
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\host-manager has finished in 156 ms
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\manager
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\manager has finished in 94 ms
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\ProgramData\CertAccordServer\tomcat\webapps\ROOT has finished in 141 ms
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 93021 ms
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Mar 22, 2016 12:49:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
```

Comment: The 3 logs you mention (`commons-daemon`, `stdout`, `stderr`) are created by `procrun` as the Windows Service runner. Those logs are unrelated to your log4j configuration.

Comment: Ahhh!!!  No wonder.  Now that I know its procrun I few google searches gives me the info I need.  Procrun apparantly creates a new log file each day.  I will have my servlet directly delete tomcat/logs/* files older than X days.

Comment: So, that's good, but you still haven't gotten log4j to work properly, right?